# how to disable nautilus-dropbox in KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, dropbox, multiple-desktops

On Ubuntu 12.10 64bit I additionally installed kubuntu-desktop. I installed dropbox in Unity to use it there with nautilus. In Kde this is not the wanted behavior so I installed the dropboxd - Daemon and enabled it to autostart in KDE. But the nautilus-dropbox applet is always started in addition to the daemon.

How can I make sure that there is ONLY the dropboxd running and NOT the nautilus-dropbox when I use KDE and When using Gnome I llike to use nautilus-dropbox?

plz note that there is no setting for nautilus-dropbox in KDE autostart applications!

Maybe there is a way to install two versions and make sure only the right one is started with each desktop environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is from a quick Google search and is a bit old, but http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/01/17/install-dropbox-on-kubuntu-kde-without-nautilus/ covers how to install Dropbox and get it working w/o all the dependencies and the notifier running.  Might still work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Right click in the applet, `Preferences/General` and disable `Start Dropbox on system startup`.

Comment: First of all I don't have the option and secondly I still get an applet in KDE and it still calls nautilus. Could you be more specific?

Comment: And how do I have the applet in Gnome/Unity if I disable it?